# How to initialize the InMobi SDK in swift?

Tags: swift, initialization, ads, inmobi

I am trying to use InMobi in my app but I do not know how to initialize it. I have everything downloaded to my project but the support for Inmobi does not have Swift version so I am lost.

This is where I am stuck.

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually i don't have `InMobi` SDK so giving you this advice:-Type `IMDDK(`, and wait for autocorrect/autofill.

Comment: That does nothing

Comment: there's swift samples here..https://github.com/InMobi/sdk-sample-code-ios

Comment: is this resolved?